# getContentResolver().delete doesn't work

Tags: android, uri, contacts, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to delete a specific contact! I've searched a lot, but every code I try doesn't work!

```
public void delete(String name,String numero)
{
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

while (cur.moveToNext())
{
    try
    {
        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{String.valueOf(numero)};
        String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, Phone.NUMBER +"=?", selectionArgs);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

}

I also tried this instead of specifying selectionArgs but nothing

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +"="+ name, null);
```

and tried to change `Contacts.` with `ContactsContract.Contacts.` but nothing
and yet tried deleting with the Contact displayname instead of number.
It seems that selection doesnt work! The uri value is `Uri$HierarchicalUri` is this right?

What's the issue?

Comment: Have you set the right permissions?

Comment: Yes, but now all the contacts will be deleted, while i want to delete only the contact with that number

Comment: I had a similar problem but not with contacts... Try to set the value in quotes, e.g. `+ " = '" + name"'"`(single quotes ' )

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +"="+ name, null);
```

to

```
String[] names = {name};
getContentResolver().delete(uri, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +"=?", names);
```

Comment: Still not work! I tried with Phone.NUMBER instead of display name but is not working! It continue to delete all contacts